# Transform after groupby in dask

Tags: pandas, dask

I'm looking to perform a transform-like operation after a groupby using dask dataframes.  Looking through the docs, it doesn't seem like dask currently gives this option - but does anyone have any work around?

In practice: I'm looking to subtract the means of column B (after doing a groupby on A) from the raw values of B.  In pure pandas, it looks like this:

```
def demean_and_log(x):
    x_log = np.log(x)
    x_log_mean = x_log.mean()
    return x_log - x_log_mean

log_demean_col = X.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(demean_and_log)
```

However, this is *very* slow - as I'm dealing with very large dataframes, and since I'm using a custom transformation function in Python, pandas doesn't release the GIL.

Comment: You may want to look at this issue https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2536